# htaccess redirect subdomain to subfolder of another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using .htaccess to proxy redirect the content of a subdomain to a subfolder of another domain as:
**www.domain1.com/support**
will show content from
**site1-support.domain2.com**

While keeping the address bar showing hxxp://www.domain1.com/support.

To do this, I've created an empty folder called "support" under www.domain1.com and add this to .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?support/(.*)$ http://site1-support.domain1.com/$1?proxy=http://site1-support.domain2.com [P]
</IfModule>
```

This works, but whenever there is ? in the url it doesn't show the page, such as 
hxxp://www.domain1.com/kb.php?article=1

Any help from htaccess gurus out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to forward the `article=1` with the `RedirectRule` you should add the [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag.

```
RewriteRule ^/?support/(.*)$ http://site1-support.domain1.com/$1?proxy=http://site1-support.domain2.com [QSA,P]
```

Hope it helps, and that I understood your question correctly. :)